# Array issue in rails and highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm having issues in display data from my array in the series section of my lazy highcharts code. The 'dates' variable works fine in the 'f.options[:xAxis][:categories] = dates' section, but comes up blank in the 'f.series(:type => 'area', :name => 'Degree', :data => temps, :color => '#00463f')' and I'm not sure why this is.

The data comes from an uploaded csv file which I have used the paperclip gem to achieve.

Controller

```
def show
    @soiltemp = Soiltemp.find(params[:id])
    @data = CSV.open(@soiltemp.csv.path, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
    dates = []
    temps = []
    @data.each do |row|  
     dates << row[1]
     temps << row[2]
    end
    @graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.options[:xAxis][:categories] = dates 
      f.series(:type => 'area', :name => 'Degree', :data => temps, :color => '#00463f' ) 
      f.series(:type => 'spline',:name => 'Average', :data => [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33]) 
    end
    end
```

Comment: Have you printed out the `temps` value?

Comment: Yes, and it works fine, as it prints out a list of temperatures. So i'm puzzled as to why it won't register in my high charts code.

Comment: Are they strings or are they numbers?

Comment: numbers, but the csv isn't loaded as columns in my database, but as a file.

Comment: Would you mind posting the value of `temps.inspect` prior to the `LazyHighCharts` call?

Comment: In my view? I have to make it a global variable to be able to call. It renders ["24", "24", "24", "23", "23", "22"...]etc. I appreciate your help on this Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts is expecting numbers for the series. You're passing strings in your `temps` array. Use `row[2].to_i` (if they are integers) when building up `temps`.

Comment: Perfect. Can't thank you enough Peter. Don't why I didn't think of that option!